# What was this pirate themed platform game for 8 bit computers?

Tags: identify-this-game

I recall playing a game which I think was about pirates. It was a platform game for an 8 bit system, a computer I believe, and sold in the UK. Set on a ship with item collecting.

Does anyone know this game?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## [Booty?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Booty_(video_game)):

> Booty is a platform game published in 1984 for the Amstrad CPC, Commodore 64, Commodore Plus/4, and ZX Spectrum. The game was one of Firebird's initial releases.
>
> The player takes on the role of a cabin boy who attempts to steal a hoard of treasure from his pirate masters. A variety of hazards must be avoided including pirates, parrots and booby-trapped treasure. Should the player manage to collect all the treasure, he is given 45 seconds to find a final key, which will restart the game.
>
> There are a total of 20 screens in the game which contain a mixture of collectable treasure, doors to other screens, and doors which act as obstacles and can only be unlocked by collecting the appropriate numbered key. Some rooms contain non-player character pirates, contact with which will cause the loss of one of the player's three lives.

[image] [image]

> The first budget game I, and many of us, ever bought for the Spectrum. Published on British Telecom’s Firebird label, Booty was a rough around the edges, pirate-centric platform game, that I hold a special affection for seeing as it was the only game I could afford at the time I got it. It wasn’t massive, with just 20 screens to venture through, and there’s not much originality to the idea of picking up lots of treasure. It snuck up on you though, and while it was always easy to pick holes in, Booty consistently entertained. It boasted some of the finest colour clash to be seen on Sir Clive’s old baby, too.
>
> — Simon Brew: ["The top 50 underappreciated ZX Spectrum games
> The humble Spectrum was home to some remarkable games - including these underappreciated masterpieces...", Den of Geek, March 22, 2013.](https://www.denofgeek.com/games/the-top-50-underappreciated-zx-spectrum-games/)

> [General info for: Booty [#ID: 633] / Spectrum Computing](https://spectrumcomputing.co.uk/index.php?cat=96&id=0000633)
>
> [image] [image]

A [video of the original  game play (on C-64)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kAe_IvnEpnk). [Entry on MyAbandonware.](https://www.myabandonware.com/game/booty-4ls#download) Newer [remake of the ZX Spectrum version, from 2019](https://playonretro.itch.io/booty-zx-spectrum).

Comment: Thank you, that's it! Great work and now I'm looking forward to playing this game again. Once I saw the screenshot I remembered the numbered keys immediately.

Answer (score 8):

- [Captain Silver](https://www.mobygames.com/game/captain-silver)

  [image: Captain Silver Sega Master System]

---

- [Swashbuckler](https://www.mobygames.com/game/swashbuckler)

  [image: Swashbuckler Apple II]

---

- [Skull & Crossbones](https://www.mobygames.com/game/skull-crossbones)

  [image: Skull & Crossbones Commodore 64]

---

- [Treasure Island](https://www.mobygames.com/game/treasure-island_____)

  [image: Treasure Island Commodore 16]

---

- [Tales of the Arabian Nights](https://www.mobygames.com/game/tales-of-the-arabian-nights) might easily be mistaken for a pirate game too

  [image: Tales of the Arabian Nights Amstrad CPC]

Comment: Oh! the hours lost playing Swashbuckler...

Comment: Wasn't the last one the one with Rimsky-Korsakov music? I discovered him through that game...

Answer (score 2):

.................... [Pirates!](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Sid_Meier%27s_Pirates!)?

Comment: I wouldn't call that a platform game though (i.e. Super Mario, games that revolve around actual platforms). But I can't think of any pirate games that were platform based.

Comment: Thanks, but it was not that game. It was a platform game on a ship.

Comment: I played Sid Meier's Pirates in the 80's, but it was definitely not a platform game. Great game though!